# process Environment for testing - DB -Nodejs

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, development-environment, production-environment

could someone tell me how to stop storing data into mongoDB in Test environment in nodejs via process environment variable. just want to run the node app like follow

ex: test dbConnection = false node index.js

many thanks for any help

Comment: Well you can't stop your script from executing queries you can setup/clean your database when in development or testing environment quite often. I assume that you use the same Database in development and production which is bad practice. Try setting environmental variables with `set` or have another script to load build an configuration object that you can use everywhere.

Comment: can you throw examples

Comment: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-project-structure-tutorial-node-js-at-scale take a look the way it structures  configuration